# Neither call by reference or call by name worked for dynamic collection name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I was trying to dynamically provide the collection name and do queries on it like this:

```
databaseName.findOne({"type":"starsCount"})
```

However, neither call-by-references or call-by-name from [this tutorial](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/collections-by-reference) works here.

In my fixture file to setup data, I called the methods to request data from github API.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.call('accessGitAPI','facebook','react','reactInfo')
```

In a file that declares the meteor methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
    accessGitAPI:function(userName,repoName,databaseNameString){
        var databaseName = global[databaseNameString]
        HTTP.call( 'GET', `https://api.github.com/repos/${userName}/${repoName}`, 
            {
                headers: 
                {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    "Accept":"application/vnd.github.v3+json",
                    "User-Agent": "whales"
                },
            },
            function( error, response ) {
          if ( error ) {

            console.log( error );
          } else {

            let responseData = response.data;

            let starsCountAlreadyExist = databaseName.findOne({"type":"starsCount"})

            let issuesCountAlreadyExist = databaseName.findOne({'type':'issuesCount'})


          }
        });
    }

});
```

By searching for that string in the global object, I ended up getting undefined for the result.

Error:

```
Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
```

Then I decided to use call-by-reference. I directly used the database reference as a argument to pass into the function. Then I removed the line to search for the object in the global namespace. In the fixture file:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {ReactInfo} from '../../api/react_info.js'

Meteor.call('accessGitAPI','facebook','react',ReactInfo)
```

However this results in another error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

react_info.js

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
export const ReactInfo = new Mongo.Collection('reactInfo');
```

Not sure why neither is working. The tutorial makes perfect sense but it is just not working. I also don't understand why the call stack error is happening after I added the import and pass the database reference directly as an argument.

Comment: Are you passing the name as String? It shouldn't be string. I wrote a somewhat similar thing so instead of 'collectionName' it should be collectionName tho I didn't pass it from the client. I passed an arguement from client and wrote cases to set collection name.

Comment: Yeah that's what I eventually did. Based on the string I use cases to point the variable to different database on the server side.  I was just wondering why the methods from the tutorial aren't working. The author seemed to be able to do both call-by-reference with database reference and call-by-name with database name string.